# Using a variable in a regular expression (regex)

Tags: python, regex, python-re

So I have a dictionary of words and their numbers, and a list of texts that I need to search through to find matches of words (and sum of numbers) from a dictionary under certain conditions.

Conditions:

- Only exact matches. eg, #abandon or @abandon or abandoning or abandon-this are not exact matches for 'abandon'
- If it ends with these punctuations: !,?.'" it is an exact match eg. do not abandon!
- Text can have multiple matches eg. "sad to abandon this project" would match 'sad' and 'abandon'
- Words are case insensitive, ie "LoSeR" would match 'loser'

So for 'abandon', any of these can match:

- "Abandon"
- "abandon."
- "abandon "
- "ABANDON"

```
dictionary = {"abandon":-2, "love":4, "hate":-4, "loser":-4, "positive":2}
text = ["he was abandoned at a young age, but he found his love", "think positive", "he is such a loser", "WHY DO YOU HATE ME?", "I love you and I am positive about it"] 
pattern = r'word[ !,\?\.'"]' #something i attempted but does not work
score = 0
score_list = []
for t in text:
   for word in dictionary:
      match = re.findall(re.escape(word), text)
      for m in match:
         score += dictionary[word]
   score_list.append(score)
```

The `score_list` should be `[4,2,-4,-4,6]`.

With the dictionary of words and their respective numbers and a list of text, I find all the matches of words, sum the respective numbers of the matching words, and store in the `score_list`.

I can't figure out how to make the regex so it can match the exact conditions such as exact matches, punctuation it can end with, and case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall), creating a pattern on the fly for each key in your dictionary, and then multiply the number of the occurrences you found times the correspondent value and sum all (it is longer to explain than to code):

```py
[sum(len(re.findall("(\.\s*|\s|^){}(\s|!|\?|\.|$)".format(k), s, re.IGNORECASE)) * v for k, v in dictionary.items()) for s in text]
```

Output:

```sh
[4, 2, -4, -4, 6]
```

The pattern is `"(\.|\s+){}(\s+|!|\?|$)+"`, i.e., the word you are looking for preceded by a space or a full stop or the beginning of the string, and followed by a space or `!` or `?` or the end of the string (`$`). `findall` is case insensitive, due to the flag `re.IGNORECASE`.